# what does Glide do when disk storage is full?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-glide

I am using Glide in my Android application for loading images from internet. I've disabled `memoryCache` when loading images but `diskCache` is still active and it uses default strategy to cache resources on the disk. My question is What Glide do during caching resources on the disk storage if disk's storage is full and there isn't any free space on it? Will it throw and exception or what?

Answer (score 1):

No it wont throw any errors. but it might give a callback in

```
@Override
public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
  super.onLoadFailed(e, errorDrawable);
}
```

Currently Glide downloads the whole image and decodes it. Then fails to write the cache and error is displayed. Next time it tries it'll download it again, and do the same thing. If this proposal is implemented it would fail at writing cache, but since it displays the image next time it MAY hit the cache and prevent downloading again. So this fix would save bandwidth and enhance UX. because of this Glide may not load images when device space run out.

Hope this answers to your question